# Posting a Tweet using Oauth

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter, oauth

I'm trying to create a web application that will allow a user to post a tweet from a form directly on the webpage, instead of using Twitter's own pre-built pop-up. The problem is, the snippet of code that I'm seeing around the web is not working:

```
$message = "Hello there! This is a tweet!";

$twitterObj->post('statuses/update', array('status' => "$message"));
```

And when I try to execute the code I get this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /twitter/EpiOAuth.php on line 76

Warning: http_build_query() [function.http-build-query]: Parameter 1 expected to be Array or      Object. Incorrect value given in /twitter/EpiOAuth.php on line 140

I'm building off the example and using the OAuth library found at this web address:

http://www.jaisenmathai.com/articles/twitter-php-sign-in.html

Does anyone have any tips?

---

EDIT

Problem solved! It turns out that this was the correct statement that I needed to use:

```
$twitterObj->post_statusesUpdate(array('status' => 'Message goes here.'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I use:

```
$message = "Hello there! This is a tweet!";

$twitterObj->OAuthRequest('https://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml', array('status' => $message), 'POST');
```

This is with the library found here: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

Comment: Thank you for the help!

I replaced my code with yours and it looks like the errors have disappeared, but it still doesn't post a tweet. So it recognizes it, but it doesn't look like it's executing it.

Comment: Do you have write access enabled for your app on Twitter's end?

Comment: Yes, I set it to "Read, Write, and access direct messages" for testing purposes and dialed it back down to simply "Read and Write" and it still didn't work.

Comment: Would I need to edit anything under the "OAuth Tool" tab in Twitter's application settings?

Comment: This actually depends on the OAuth library that you're using.  This uses https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth